# ISAP lightweight crypto algorithm

Tags: encryption

I am reading the documentary of ISAP lightweight crypto algorithm and find a kind of weird definition.

S = Sr (concatenate sign) Sc      The n-bit sponge state S with r-bit outer part Sr and c-bit inner part Sc

Does it mean outer part Sr is MSB and inner part Sc is LSB?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2hrH.png)

Comment: This question seems to have nothing to do with VHDL. Perhaps there's more to it than your're showing us? If so, add this detail to the question.

Comment: It means that the state of the sponge construction is comprised of r (rate) bits on the left and c (capacity) bits on the right. Whether this is MSB or LSB is up to the implementation.

Comment: Do you know that there is also a cryptography site? It's at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ ... because there is terribly little in the form of programming required to answer the question, it seems to me.